# Opening spreadsheet returns InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, django

I have a user uploading a file to a website and I need to parse the spreadsheet. Here is my code:

```
input_file = request.FILES.get('file-upload')
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(input_file)
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError at /upload_spreadsheet/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found
```

Why is this happening and what do I need to do to fix it? Thank you.

For reference, this is how I open the file in the shell

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/me/dave_example.xls')
<xlrd.Book object at 0x10d9f7390>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to get a hold of the spread sheet (eg, are you in a position to have the user email it to you?).  Getting the file somewhere local and verifying it isn't corrupt would be useful - if possible.

Comment: @Dave - No, unfortunately I cannot do that. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can dump the InMemoryUploadedFile to a temp file before opening with xlrd.

```
try:
    fd, tmp = tempfile.mkstemp()
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as out:
        out.write(input_file.read())
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(tmp)
    ...  # do what you have to do
finally:
    os.unlink(tmp)  # delete the temp file no matter what
```

If you want to keep everything in memory, try:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=None, file_contents=input_file.read())
```

Comment: The disk write seems not necessary. Isn't there a way how to avoid it?

Comment: @PetrPeller: If you have the file contents in memory you can use the `file_contents` parameter instead when calling `open_workbook`; it is a string (or an `mmap.mmap` object or some other behave-alike object). If file_contents is supplied, filename will not be used, except (possibly) in messages.

Comment: i had to use like "wb = xlrd.open_workbook(**filename=None**, file_contents=input_file.read())" to work properly

Comment: second one is too simple and its works well for me. thanks @PauloScardine